How to open the photo used by windows photos in start menu?
When in Windows 10 I click Start, in Start Menu Windows shows Photos application gadget with one on the photos taken randomly from my collection. When I click it, it opens the Photos application with all my collection.
Is there a way to open exactly the photo which was used by the gadget, not looking for it in the collection?
Sometimes it shows photos of interest and I'd like to look them full screen, but it is hard to find them in the collection.
